# Php code to read multiple file and return the last line

Tags: php, file, foreach

Am trying to read multiple file and display the last line of each file but my code is not working very fine i don't know what am doing wrong.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['fid'], $_GET['timestamp']) && !empty($_GET['fid'])){

$lastmodif = isset( $_GET['timestamp']) ?  $_GET['timestamp']: 0 ;  
$fl_session = preg_replace("/[^0-9=]+/", "", $_GET['fid']);


if(strpos($fl_session, '==') !== false) {
$fl_session = explode('==', $fl_session);

    foreach($fl_session as $fn){
        $filename = dirname(__FILE__).'/logs/foo_'.$fn.'.txt';
        $currentmodif = filemtime($filename);

        while($currentmodif <= $lastmodif) {
          usleep(10000);
          clearstatcache();
          $currentmodif = filemtime($filename);
        }
          if(file_exists($filename)){
            $myfile = fopen($filename, "r") or die("Unable to load readme file!"); 
            if($myfile){
                $log = fread($myfile, filesize($filename));
                fclose($myfile); 
            }
            $log = explode("\n", trim($log));
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($log); $i++) {
                $log[$i] = trim($log[$i]);
                $log[$i] = explode('|', $log[$i]);
            }
             foreach ($log as $logline) {
                $response['id'] = trim($logline['0']);
                $response['type'] = trim($logline['3']);
             }
          }
          $response[$fn]['timestamp'] = $currentmodif;
          //$response['timestamp'] = $currentmodif;
          //var_export($response);
          echo json_encode($response);
    }
}

}
```

In my `GET['fid']` parameter it contain something like this `12345==09765==87765`, so i will explode it and loop on every id to locate the file name `foo_12345.txt, foo_09765.txt, foo_87765.txt`. This current code returned something like this from one txt file and ignored other files.

> { "id":"58287469", "type":"client", "8942180223":{
>     "timestamp":1505409432 } } { "id":"53094615", "type":"client",
>   "8942180223":{ "timestamp":1505409432 }, "4582422934":{
>   "timestamp":1505409420 } }

Comment: Why do you loop through all the lines of the file when you only need the last one? After explode \n, you can use end($log); as the last line of the array

Comment: @Andreas, please am still very new to php, am trying to make a long pulling chat this is my first attempt of doing that. I will appreciate if you post an answer to it

Comment: My code is working when using it for a single file, but trying to read multiple file is giving me problem

Comment: Have you tested that `$fl_session` actually contains proper values after `explode`? What have you tried/tested? Having a "problem" is very ambiguous.

Comment: @William_Wilson yes, `$fl_session`  contain the values even after i exploded it i got the array of values

Comment: It is possible you are getting stuck in the `while`. If the modification time doesn't change on your second file `$currentmodif` will be assigned the same value over and over which is always less than `$lastmodif`.